# Read Property Values in Cypress_Json File

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am trying to reach out to the "testdata":"two" property values [like 'EH']. While I was taking that property, I am facing "Cannot read property" this issue, How I fix this issue in Cypress?

```
[{
        "testdata": "one",
        "TC": {
            "EHQ0": "Address",
            }

    },
    {
        "testdata": "two",
        "TC": {
            "EH": "Student",
            "E1": "Question For Name",
            "EnglishText_E1": "Question For Name"
        }

    }
]
```

Comment: How are you trying to access these values in code?

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of objects, so either index or find.

```js
const data = [{
        "testdata": "one",
        "TC": {
            "EHQ0": "Address",
            }

    },
    {
        "testdata": "two",
        "TC": {
            "EH": "Student",
            "E1": "Question For Name",
            "EnglishText_E1": "Question For Name"
        }

    }
]

const objTwo = data.find(obj => obj.testdata === 'two')
const ehProp = objTwo.TC.EH
```

Comment: I have implemented this concept in cypress. but I was getting the below error "data.find is not a function". I can't able to update the screenshot here

Comment: describe('Retrive a json Property', () => {
  let sdata
 before(()=> {
  cy.fixture('filename').then(function(ldata){
   sdata=ldata
  });
  });
it('TC-01_StudentDetails', () => {
  cy.log(sdata.testdata.TC)
  sdata.forEach(data => {
   cy.log(data)
  if(data.testdata=="two")
  {
   cy.log(data.testdata.TC.EHQ0)
  
  }
  
 })
})
})

I have Updated my code. I am using the fixture to retrieve the JSON data in cypress, So, I can't able to set a const data in JSON file and it was taking an error

Comment: TypeError data.find is not a function cypress/e2e/TestCases/TC-1.cy.js:36:23 34 | const objTwo = data.find(obj =>obj.testdata =='TestcaseaName') | ^ 37 | const ehProp = objTwo.TC.EH 38 | cy.log(ehProp) 39 | // cy.log(data.testdata)

Comment: Follow my example and all will become clear. `data` is an array, `.find()` is an array method - no error occurs.